# 3D Gussian Splatting looks strange after import

Tags: modeling, rendering, geometry-nodes, photogrammetry, 3dgs

I am trying to import a 3D Gaussian Splatting scan into Blender using the [plugin](https://github.com/ReshotAI/gaussian-splatting-blender-addon) from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3OaxR70FIU&ab_channel=MassimoVendola). But for some reason, the scan looks terrible in Blender (although in Unreal it looks like it should). I tried to reduce the size of the particles, but this only leads to an empty space between them. How can I fix this?

This is how it looks in Blender:
[image]

And this is how it looks in Unreal:
[image]